# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.6

My Spark Consumer is failing with "logging" error. I found while browsing the error is due to incompatibility of jars. 
I am using Spark 1.6.3 and all the dependencies is used in pom,xml are 1.6.3. Still I am getting the same error. Below is my maven structure and error throwing while executing.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
    at datapipeline.SparkConsumer.main(SparkConsumer.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
```

my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.iot.app.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>iotanalytics</artifactId>
    <!-- <packaging>jar</packaging> -->
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>IoT Kafka Producer</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency> 
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId> 
        <version>2.8.2</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spark-project.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>unused</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId> <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId> 
            <version>2.11.8</version> </dependency> -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried saving your pom.xml, right-click on your project, and mavan build? Maybe it's just no updated.

Comment: You can simply do Ctrl+Shift+T and search for "Logging"  class, and if you can see more than one versions of same , then it means it is loading old one dependency [which is called transitive maven dependency] which you need to solve by excluding it pom.

Comment: @MonisMajeed I also tried building the project a fresh by deleting all the jar in repository. Still no luck. I

Comment: @Nathan I also tried building the project a fresh by deleting all the jar in repository. Still no luck

Comment: I didn't said delete the project which obviously is not going to help you, i said check whether you have that Logging class first, if yes then check then check it comes with what dependency , then in pom for that dependency write exclusion.

Comment: @user3837415 Does this link help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756938/geting-error-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-internal-logging-on-kafka-sp ?

Answer (score 0):

There were jars present of lower version of spark which i buil previously. Those did not got flushed out.
I deleted old version jars and reviewed my pom.xml and made sure all the dependencies  has the same version and built the project.
Program run successfully. Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.iot.app.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>DeviceStreaming</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>DeviceStreaming</name>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.11</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.0</version> </dependency> -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>





        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
             <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spark-project.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>unused</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>








        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.onosproject/onos-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onos-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
             <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
            <artifactId>bijection-avro_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>


</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Class `org.apache.spark.Logging` is available in Spark version 1.5.2 or lower not in the higher versions.

Try downgrading your Spark version to 1.5.2

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do newer versions of Spark logging? I cant imagine that they abandoned logging? In other words: shouldnt there be a replacement for this library that matches the newer spark version the OP is using? It sounds wrong to downgrade the whole thing in order to get it working ...

Comment: You mean org.apache.spark.internal.Logging ?

Comment: Logging is always present in Spark you guys can check as a dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the replay. I cannot downgrade the project as i need to use some new features introduced beyond 1.5.X. As well as i cannot go beyond 1.6.3 version as i observed lot many depedency and context issues which i got fed up. 1.6.3 is some what stable and comfortable.

Comment: @user3837415 I thought that you would have good reasons to ask for a specific versions. But I am not a spark expert, I can't tell you how to fix this problem on this level. And doing a quick bit of research - it seems most answers suggest to either downgrade or upgrade spark as a whole ;-(