# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-kafka-integration

I'm trying to run an application made up with spark structured streaming - data input from kafka.
Spark version is 2.4.0, scala version is 2.12.7.
And I'm making multiple fat-jar using sbt - my project is multi-module project.
Building jar is not a problem. When I try to `spark-submit` with my jar, `NoSuchMethodError` is occured.

1. I removed `provided` scope from `spark-sql-kafka-0-10`.

`val sparkSqlKafka = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion`

2. In `assemblyMergeStrategy` I added line below.

`case "META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister" => MergeStrategy.concat`

This is whole error log.

```
2019-01-08 11:55:12 ERROR ApplicationMaster:91 - User class threw exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:161)
    at ThisIsMyClass$.main(ThisIsMyClass.scala:28)
    at ThisIsMyClass.main(ThisIsMyClass.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:678)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.<init>(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 19 more
```

---

Edit 1.

Whole dependencies below.

```
val sparkVersion = "2.4.0"
val typesafeConfigVersion = "1.3.3"
val scalaTestVersion = "3.0.5"
val junitVersion = "4.12"
val sparkCore = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkSql = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkMllib = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val typesafeConfig = "com.typesafe" % "config" % typesafeConfigVersion
val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % Test
val junit = "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test
val logback = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
val scalaLogging = "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0"
val sparkStreaming = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided"
val sparkSqlKafka = "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
```

---

Edit 2.

I found some dependency version issue with my `slf4j-api`.

So I've changed my build configuration to using only one version of `slf4j-api` - version matches with `spark-core` dependency. And excluded other `slf4j-api`.

And still SAME Error. :(

---

Edit 3.

I've added `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.0` in my `spark-submit` script.

And still SAME Error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geting error NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging on Kafka Spark Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756938/geting-error-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-internal-logging-on-kafka-sp)

Comment: @AlexDing I read that question but I think it's different little with mine. My problem is `NoSuchMethodError` and the problem you linked is `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: I have same problem. And downgrading scala version help. But do some one find way to resolve this for scala 2.12 – Grigoriev Nick just now   edit   delete

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem solved.

When I opened `spark-shell`, I found spark version is **2.4.0** and scala version is **2.11**.
My scala version in `build.sbt` was **2.12**.

Scala version was the key!

Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

please update your dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: can you print your dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`, maybe the cause is dependencies conflicts.

Comment: I've added whole dependencies in my original question.

Comment: It's not complete, there are always lots of dependencies in a project. Dependency A1 maybe depends on B1 and C1, dependency A2 maybe depends on B2 and D1, A1 and A2 depends on different version of B(1 and 2), but not all version of B is kept, if B1 is kept and it does not have method m1 which is necessary for A2, a NoSuchMethodError will be thrown, so we have to check dependencies and what it depends, command `mvn dependency:tree` will help us to find duplicated and conficting dependency.

Comment: for example, I have met similar problem before. I have to exclude dependencies from elastic search client. So I add exclusion to my pom file:             `<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                ...etc`

Comment: Okay I understand. I will try what you said in sbt.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about the deployment environment? You running it on a cluster? Are you using cloudera or HDP or something like that? Maybe cluster environment spark version does not match your dev environment.

Comment: @PietariKettunen Yes I running it on a cluster, and my cluster env spark version is matching with dev env. Both spark version is 2.4.0. There is no problem when I run my application locally. I think.. maybe something wrong with my fat jar. I tried `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.0` when I run  `spark-submit` with my fat jar, and didn't work. :(

Comment: I've added Edit 2.

Comment: I have same problem. And downgrading scala version help. But do some one find way to resolve this for scala 2.12