# cannot display hive databases in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-shell

I run this command

`spark-shell` and it works

```bash
--files /home/hadoop/spark/conf/hive-site.xml --master spark://nodemaster:7077  --jars   $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-metastore-2.3.4.jar,  $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-exec-2.3.4.jar,  $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-common-2.3.4.jar,  $HIVE_HOME/lib/hde-2.3.4.jar,  $HIVE_HOME/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar,  $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-hive_2.11-2.4.0.jar,  $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.4.0.jar,  $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-sql_2.11-2.4.0.jar   --conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=2.3   --conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=$HIVE_HOME"/lib/*"   --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=hdfs://172.20.1.1:9000/user/hive/metastore   --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive
```

but when i run this

```scala
val databases = spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES")
```

I got this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 

org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/internal/Logging;)V

  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.<init>(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:41)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:56)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:79)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)

  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: You're manually passing all those options to the shell? Are you actual using Spark 2.4.0 (which is quite old)? And Scala 2.11? If you searched your error message, you'd find others solved this by changing their scala version https://stackoverflow.com/q/54085459/2308683